# AlertDialog dismiss not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the following AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.title);
dialogBuilder.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.message));
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive, new MyOnClickListener());
dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative, new MyOnClickListener());
dialogBuilder.show();
```

with this ClickListener

```
public static class MyOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

I would expect the dialog to be closed, when clicking on either of the buttons, but the dialog stays open instead.

I debugged the onClick method and the line

```
dialog.dismiss()
```

is being executed, but nothing happens.

Where am I going wrong or how can I fix this?

Comment: Where is your class implementation? In the same file?

Comment: Yes, they are both in the same POJO.

Comment: Insted of creating class, try interface and implement it.

Comment: as the code is small I reccomend u to add both clicklistener individually...

Comment: It implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Comment: I am using the OnClickListener in more places, just provided a test case here.

Comment: Maybe AlertDialogBuilder should be AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: Does your app reach `onClick` on `MyOnClickListener`? Adding a breakpoint there and debug might show something.

Comment: why are you creating object of static class??\

Comment: Does your `MyOnClickListerner`s onClick() method ever gets called?

Comment: @VivekMishra Because inner classes can cause memory leaks if they have a reference to the enclosing class. This is especially risky with callbacks such as Listeners.

Comment: try this as your first line 
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

Comment: Could it be that you are showing >1 dialogs and upon pressing the positive or negative button, the current dialog is indeed dismissed but there is another one identical behind it that shows up? Where do you create the dialog in your activity? Is it placed somewhere where it could be run more than 1 time?

Comment: @VivekMishra Then setPositiveButton no longer works

Answer (score 14):

Declare your `AlertDialog` at the top like:

```
private AlertDialog myAlertdialog;
```

then replace your `dialogBuilder.show();` with

```
myAlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
myAlertDialog.show();
```

then you can call `myAlertDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: What is the difference between this create() and the .show() that I am doing? Why is .create() better?

Comment: `create()` is used to create the dialog, so u can use dialog instance to access the dialog in **specific method(s)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying below code while using `interface` to create your own dialog button click listener.

**MyOnClickListener.java**

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public interface MyOnClickListener extends DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which);
}
```

Your **dialog** Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("You Title");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Here Is your message");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", new MyOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YES Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("NO", new MyOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.show();
```

**Output:**

Open your dialog:

[image: Your dialog]

Performing OnClick of dialog:

[image: OnClick of dialog]

I hope its helps you.

Comment: I can't reference MainActivity.this, because all of this code is in a POJO. Right now I am passing Context to this POJO. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: You can pass your context by replace `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: How is your code different from mine? It's almost the same except that the listener is an anonymous inner class here. Also, I don't see any dismiss in the code, how is the dialog dismissed?

Comment: While using interface you need to write your code in implemented interface methods.See my updated answer to add `dialog.dismiss();` in code for dismiss your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dialog.dismiss()` ,  use `dialoginterface.dismiss()`  .

I've shown an example below

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) 
{
    dialogInterface.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ... it worked for me ... You can use this method for your dialog 
or you can simply use  **alert.dismiss();**    to dismiss the dialog .... or just put the dialog method in your code and call the method i.e. **MyAlertDialogBox();** wherever you want a dialog box .

```
AlertDialog alert;
// Dialog method .
private void MyAlertDialogBox(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Welcome ! This is a Alert dialog")
            .setCancelable(false)
            //You can name you strings according to your preference here 
            //or the String.xml file
            .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivityName.this, "Toast message 
 when you click Yes ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton( getResources().getString(R.string.no), 
 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivityName.this, "Toast message 
 when you click No ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   //                        To dismiss your alert dialog box on click of 
     No button (or you can say the negative button)
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            });

    //Creating dialog box
    alert = builder.create();
    /*   To give dialog box title   
        alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.folder));*/

     /*    to set icon in alert dialog box
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_create_new_folder_white_24dp);*/
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you change the line `dialogBuilder.show()` to `dialogBuilder.create().show()` it should be working correctly.

Comment: show() function doesnot return anything it is void function.