# Android: AlertDialog not closing on Cancel() nor on Dismiss()

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I have implemented an AlertDialog, that works as a message dialog. When the user types the messages, he can click on the button "SEND" or the button "CANCEL". The button "SEND" works fine, but the cancel button doesn't work for some reason.

```
findViewById(R.id.contactfab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Frontpage.this);
                final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                LayoutInflater inflater = Frontpage.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_contact, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

                final EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.contactText);
                editText.setText("");
                dialogView.findViewById(R.id.send_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String [] reciever = new String[]{"test@hotmail.com"};
                        String subject = ("Feedback");
                        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, reciever);
                        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
                        mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Vælg en applikation til at sende din mail med"));
                    }
                });

                dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                dialogBuilder.show();
            }
        });
```

In order to test whether it is listening on the cancel button, I have tried to make it print a string whenever the button is clicked. The string gets printed, but the dialog doesn't close. Have tried with both `dialog.dismiss()` and `dialog.dismiss()`

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with both dialog.dismiss() and dialog.dismiss()

Comment: Did any of the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554272/alertdialog-dismiss-not-working In particular, calling `dialogBuilder.create().show()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `dialogBuilder.show();` it will create a new AlertDialog with arguments provided to the builder and immediately display the dialog. As a result, this new `AlertDialog` will be different from one declared using `final AlertDialog dialog`. In short with your code `dialog` declared will never be shown and hence `dialog.cancel()` or `dialog.close()` won't have any impact.

Change your code as follows:

```
findViewById(R.id.contactfab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Frontpage.this);

            LayoutInflater inflater = Frontpage.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_contact, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            final EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.contactText);
            editText.setText("");
            final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            dialogView.findViewById(R.id.send_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String [] reciever = new String[]{"test@hotmail.com"};
                    String subject = ("Feedback");
                    Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, reciever);
                    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
                    mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Vælg en applikation til at sende din mail med"));
                }
            });

            dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please explain this? I would like to know what was wrong.